# Yandex карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем добрый день есть следующий код код определяет текущий масштаб карты и если масштаб больше 22 то нужно задать другой масштаб например 10 подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать ??

```
mapMap.events.add('boundschange', function (event) {

    var mashtabtwoo = event.get('newZoom');

    if(mashtabtwoo > 22)
    {
        // Тут необходимо задать новый масштаб карты                    
    }

});
```

Comment: http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/map-parameters.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а зачем переменную плодить? без нее бойдемся:

```
mapMap.getZoom > 22 ? mapMap.setZoom(10) : mapMap.setZoom(mapMap.getZoom + 1);
```

Comment: Решение рабочее, только забыли скобки в `mapMap.getZoom()`.